# License Limit Exceeded Error while creating user in Sandbox

Tags: apex, error, user

I just tried using Apex in the Developer Console of my sandbox environment to create a User, and got a LICENSE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED error. There aren't very many users, and when I subsequently created a new User through the UI it was successful.

Here's the code from the Developer Console:

```
Profile profileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User' LIMIT 1];
User u = new User(
        FirstName='Joe',
        LastName='Coffee',
        Email='joe@coffee.com',
        Username='joe@coffee.com',
        Alias='joe',
        TimeZoneSidKey='GMT',
        LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
        ProfileID=profileId.id
);
insert u;
```

How do I create a User in Apex?

Comment: Do you definitely need to create the user?  You can do a System.runAs() with an un-inserted user.

Comment: Hey I thought you have to Deactivate a unnecessary user and try to do it.@Nathan Bennett

Comment: @RayDehler - no, just trying to figure out why it wasn't working through Apex, Pavan - creating the user through the UI was fine w/o deactivating any active users.

Comment: so -- this isn't for testmethod purposes -- you were using `execute anonymous apex`?

Comment: @cropredy - yeah, just testing it in the `execute anonymous apex`

Comment: hmm -- creating a new user via anon apex and creating via UI should be the same with respect to license counts -- I note in your execute anonymous you are creating an inactive user -- what did you do in the UI?

Comment: @cropredy - just the default - the user came through as active when created in the UI.